# Why i can not do this on react native render and how i do?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, render

i just wanna simple thing but i can't...

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { 
  View, 
  Button,
  ScrollView 
} from 'react-native';

const server = require("../server.json");

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.x = "oi";

  }
  render() {
    return (<ScrollView>
      <View><Text>Receitas:</Text></View>
      <View>{this.x}</View>
    </ScrollView>);
  }
}
```

this error appeared

TypeError: Failed to construct 'Text': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

Comment: Import Text.. you forgot to import Text that's why u r getting error

Answer (score 3):

There is no `Text` import from react-native.

Please add

```
import { Text } from "react-native";
```

Answer (score 0):

first this.x is text, on react native you need render text in  element.
second you should using state to use variable on react native.